# Difference between char[] and strings in C

Tags: c, string, char

The C programming language distinguishes character constants from string constants by using quotation marks in the following manner:

`'c'` is the character c, while `"c"` is a string of length 1 consisting of the single character c.

Why is this distinction made? How is it useful?
How is this different from C++?

Comment: `"c"` is a string of length 2.

Comment: `How is it useful?`---always either too broad or unclear... :-(

Comment: A string can hold more than one character (hence the name).

Comment: It's a design decision that they took. "c" is 'c' + '\0' while 'c' is just 'c'. Most of the string manipulation function will work based on that trailing '\0'

Comment: "c" is of length two.

Comment: Actually there is no string type in C. A string is simply a pointer to characters  (`char *`).

Comment: @haccks yeah, I got that via reading, but I'm not able to fathom the pros n cons of both. Like in Python, there is no such distinction, both single quote and double quote are used for a character or a string. 
What I wanted to know is the advantage and disadvantage of these two approaches. ( C approach and Python approach.)

Comment: @gfc; In python there is no datatype for character. Single and double quote is used independently.

Comment: @haccks So you think `strlen("c")` should return 2, then? I think you're just adding confusion. The length of a string does not include the terminator. The "in-memory size" does.

Comment: @unwind; I am not adding confusion. I just wanted to inform that `"c"` contains 2 characters.

Comment: Python doesn't have a character type, it only has strings. I consider the lack of a character type to be a bug in Python - that `"a"[0] == "a"` is true is just weird, and that `"a"[0][0][0]` is valid is ridiculous.

Comment: @haccks Yes, but the length of a string has a very specific meaning, at least in my world.

Comment: `"c"` is a string of length 1, and an array of 2 characters. This has been spelt out in [C11 7.1.1p1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.1p1): **"The length of a string is the *number of bytes preceding* the null character"**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**C** is [relatively] low-level statically typed programming language.

```
char c = 'c';
const char* s = "s";
```

The statements above differ not only in the value of the literal constant (c: single byte storage; s: two bytes storage + 4/8 byte pointer), but also in the type of variables (c: single byte, certain arithmetic ops; s: 4/8 byte pointer, different arithmetic).

I posit to you that the latter difference is more important; Literal constants are there to make use of variables, function arguments, struct members, etc easier.

Furthermore, the typical problems solved in C are of low-level nature where you are interested in logical difference between single character and a string. For example gpio, serial port, substring search algorithm.

[Of course C is also used in other domains, you are not likely to see much character vs string distinction in higher-level projects like `glib` or `enlightenment`.]

**Python** is a high-level dynamic language.

```
c = 'c'
s = "s"
```

In the statements above locals/labels `c` and `s` point to objects and type is determined at runtime, dynamically. Thus a distinction between a "character" and "string" is simply not needed.

Problems solved in Python are usually of much higher level, typically you'd deal with JSON blobs, HTTP requests, database queries, virtual machines, etc; Even if you need to deal with single characters, length-1 string is an acceptable approximation.

[If you used `numpy` or `cffi`, you would worry about storage of characters and strings and those modules provide mechanism to do so.]

Answer (score 8):

You are mistaken saying that

> while "c" is a string of length 1 consisting of the single character c

"c" is a character array consisting of two characters that has the static storage duration. You can imagine its definition the following way

```
char s[] = { 'c', '\0' };
```

Standard C function `strlen` deteremines the length of a string literal by searching the terminating zero and counting the number of characters before the terminating zero.

A string literal can containe only one character (terminating zero) if it is defined like `""`. For this "empty" string literal function `strlen` will return value 0.

Character integer constants or so-called character literals have type `int`. They are not character array opposite to string literals. Even a multibyte character constant like for example `'AB'` is converted to an object of type `int` and such a conversion is implementation defined. (In C++ a character literal consisting of one character has type `char` and for example `sizeof( 'A' )` is equal to 1 while a multibyte character literal has type `int` the same way as in C)

As character literals have type `int` then their sizes are fixed and equal to `sizeof( int )`.

Compare the outputs of this statements

```
printf( "%zu\n", sizeof( 'A' ) );
printf( "%zu\n", sizeof( 'AB' ) );
printf( "%zu\n", sizeof( "A" ) );
printf( "%zu\n", sizeof( "AB" ) );
```

If `sizeof( int )` is equal to 4 then you will get

```
4
4
2
3
```

Note: the compiler can issue a warning or an error for statement

```
printf( "%zu\n", sizeof( 'AB' ) );
```

Answer (score 8):

Using `'c'` will tell the compiler you want a single character, while using `"c"` will create a null terminated string (same as saying `{'c', '\0'}`), for example if you want a fixed array of chars without the zero terminator to end the string you'd use arrays of characters with single quotations, if however you want an array of characters that is zero terminated - thus suitable for using in `strlen()`, `printf()` and others you'd use double quotes.

Comment: umm, yeah makes sense. Depending upon the use case we can use both in C.

Answer (score 3):

It's a design decision that they took. "c" is 'c' + '\0' while 'c' is just 'c'. Most of the string manipulation function will work based on that trailing '\0'

Since you are trying to relate it with python. In python, everything is an object. When you create a string in python, this object also stores the string length along with the characters of the string. All the string methods will use this length info present in the string object. Character is just a string of length 1 in python.

Since C is a very old systems programming language which was supposed to work on very low memory devices, they couldn't afford to create an object with length and other stuff for every string they create. This is a memory waste. Instead they went with a single trailing '\0' character to represent the string