# Type casting and addition

Tags: c, string, int

In C I can add `'a'+10` and it will result in a valid answer... Why can I add this and why can't I add `"a"+10`?

Is `'a'` represent an integer in C and `"a"` represent a string constant

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Character vs strings in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31179386/character-vs-strings-in-c)

Comment: You *can* add a number to a `char *`, but it's undefined behavior if the resulting pointer does not point into the object pointed to by the original `char *` or just beyond it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "a" is a string literal which becomes a char array in C. 'a' is internally just a number - the ASCII value of the letter *a*.

Answer (score 0):

`"a"` returns a pointer. You can't do `"a"+10` because only 2 characters are allocated, but you could do `"Thomas"+3`. It will return a pointer to the `m`.

`'a'` returns a number. On an ASCII-based machine, it will be ninety-seven to be precise. `'a'+5` will return one hundred and two, which is the same value returned by `'e'`.

Answer (score 0):

Character constants in C have type `int`, so `'a' + 10` just adds 10 to the integer value of the character `'a'` (probably 97). (In C++, character constants are of type `char`, but `char` is still an integer type, so `'a' + 10` is equally valid in C++.)

`"a" + 10` is more complicated. `"a"` is of type `char[2]` (1 for the 'a', plus 1 for the null character that terminates the string). But array expressions are, in most contexts, implicitly converted to pointer expressions. So `"a" + 10` performs pointer arithmetic, yielding a result of the `char*`. But evaluating that expression has undefined behavior, since it points past the end of the array containing `"a"`.

For example, this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    printf("%s\n", "hello, world" + 3);
}
```

is perfectly valid, and it prints

```
lo, world
```